# How can I perfectly position 4 images in a div, 2 images per row

Tags: html, css, .net-core

I wanted to ask if you have any idea how I can position 4 images in a div. I want to achieve this:
[image]

HTML

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="AboutContent">
            <p>Text goes here</p>
        </div>
        <div id="imagesContent">
            <p>Images go here</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
#AboutContent {
    position:absolute;
    border: 5px solid orange;
    width: 50%;
    height:100vh;
    float:left;

}
#imagesContent {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

I tried several approaches and one actually worked, but there was a problem where it didn't show properly the size of the image when I wrote it. I am just giving the code, with the positioning and dimensions. Another thing to take into consideration is that the 4 images are really big.

Would appreciate if you have any ideas or suggestions!
P.S sorry for the images I couldn't find anything better to show what I want to achieve

Comment: Your code is no where close to what you are describing? Is this the code you have tried?

Comment: I tried several codes, but just had enough, deleted it and just provided the code with the dimensions and positioning. I.e i don't know how to position the 4 images perfectly in the div. I am asking if anyone can give further advice on the code I have provided or even better come up with a solution. I know that the given code will not position any images or etc.

Comment: I have posted an answer. let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="first" class="divSquare">
    <img src ="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494253109108-2e30c049369b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80" />
  </div>
  <div id="second" class="divSquare">
    <img src ="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1513171920216-2640b288471b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" />
  </div>
  <div style='clear:both'></div>
  <div id="third" class="divSquare">
    <img src ="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508138221679-760a23a2285b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1267&q=80" />
  </div>
  <div id="fourth" class="divSquare">
    <img src ="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1493612276216-ee3925520721?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=700&q=80" />
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divSquare{
    width:48%; 
    height:200px; 
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

 .divSquare img{
    width: 100%;

}
```

Link in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b5kanyrh/

Let me know if it works or if you need explaining. Its quite simple though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of possible solutions.

First I always aim to just focus on the semantic structure. In this case I would go with

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

To me the most natural approach seems to use css grid. Here's an excellent guide by CSS Tricks: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

It would look like this:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

The above snippet means that you divide the container element into two equal *fractions* (hence the unit **fr**) both horizontally and vertically. The li elements will automatically drop to one of the four grid cells that you defined by the division.

Some suggest to use other approaches because css grid is not supported by ancient browsers that should be in museums by this time, but almost no one uses them anymore, so I think it's fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, was really helpful and learned something new!